# Info button did not appear after shake gesture for heatma.ps SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, heatmap, heatma.ps

I've setup heatma.ps SDK inside my iPad app, it contains plenty of custom view controllers and I decided to track my UITableView which uses a custom UITableViewCell. <-- I hope this is not the main cause of the problem.

I've made sure  `heatmaps.showMenu = YES` is inside the app delegate.

Also, I can see swipe gestures and screen rotation printed in the output. Which means the SDK is setup properly.

However, when I shake the device or simulator, the info button is not appearing. I was concerned if it was appearing behind my table view cells, so I reduced the alpha values of them, but the info button is still not there.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to call and place the info button after the shake gesture?

Comment: hi @KineticStack, I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for. I followed the guide at https://heatma.ps/support/getting-started/installing-sdk/ and https://heatma.ps/support/getting-started/tracking-ui-elements/. And there are no specific codes during the setup process that requires me to handle the call and positioning the info button. So I had assumed they are handled by the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you shake your device (simulator or device) your tracked object in this case `UITableView` will receive a call to add info button as its subview. If you are not seeing the info button it could be due to your view architecture, something either over lays your UITableView or you didn't subclass the `UIWindow` object from `HMUIWindow` object that catches the shake motion and calls display info button methods.

**EDIT**

To find out if you properly subclassed `UIWindow` from `HMUIWindow` just shake your device and look in the console for the debug info like:

```
2011-12-26 17:10:01.963 Test[645:f803] [HEATMA.PS] Store shake for 88888888
```

Comment: hi @cyprian, sorry for the really late reply. according to what you've said. I tried shaking...but there was nothing in the console. however, when I rotate the screen, i do get...`2012-01-08 10:59:30.008 Test[8781:17c03] [HEATMA.PS] Store orientation vertical for 84d19d3d
2012-01-08 10:59:32.570 Test[8781:17c03] [HEATMA.PS] Store orientation horizontal for 84d19d3d`

Comment: I've also replaced `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;` with `@property (strong, nonatomic) HMUIWindow *window;` in my app delegate.

Comment: I figured out what happened. I should have subclassed UIWindow at `MainWindow.xib`'s inspector. Now I can see the info button and detect the shake motion. Thanks @cyprian.

Comment: @csl grate. In a week or two we will release new version of the sdk that will skip the UIWindow subclass step so you will not have to worry about it. We will also have couple other cool feature updates.